# Cannot read property 'text' of undefined at NodeObject.getText at getRequiredModulePath

Tags: angular, typescript, tsc, angular-compiler, angular-compiler-cli

Error occurs while generating browser application bundles (phase: setup).
What can cause this error?

**Info from console:**

> Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
> at NodeObject.getText (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:152697:31)
> at getRequiredModulePath (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/host/umd_host.js:519:99)
> at Object.getImportsOfUmdModule (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/host/umd_host.js:510:23)
> at UmdDependencyHost.extractImports (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/dependencies/umd_dependency_host.js:43:54)
> at UmdDependencyHost.DependencyHostBase.recursivelyCollectDependencies (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/dependencies/dependency_host.js:85:32)
> at UmdDependencyHost.DependencyHostBase.collectDependencies (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/dependencies/dependency_host.js:38:22)
> at DependencyResolver.getEntryPointWithDependencies (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/dependencies/dependency_resolver.js:75:22)
> at EntryPointCollector.walkDirectoryForPackages (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/entry_point_finder/entry_point_collector.js:47:52)
> at EntryPointCollector.walkDirectoryForPackages (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/entry_point_finder/entry_point_collector.js:75:103)
> at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/entry_point_finder/program_based_entry_point_finder.js:124:100

**Info from angular-errors.log**

> An error occurred during the build:
> Error: NGCC failed.
> at NgccProcessor.process (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:139:19)
> at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/plugin.js:129:27
> at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), :28:1)
> at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:14:14)
> at Compiler.newCompilation (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1043:30)
> at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1088:29
> at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :22:1)
> at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
> at Compiler.compile (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1083:28)
> at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:508:12
> at Compiler.readRecords (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:920:11)
> at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:505:11
> at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :10:1)
> at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
> at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:502:20
> at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :22:1)
> An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
> See "/tmp/ng-IZbyMh/angular-errors.log" for further details.

Comment: What is the content of `/tmp/ng-IZbyMh/angular-errors.log`?

Comment: @MaartenDev I edited post to be more clear

Comment: did you try removing the `node_modules` folder and running `npm i` again?

Comment: @MaartenDev yes, i tried

Comment: Are there any typescript issues reported when you run the following command: `./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --noEmit -p .`?

Comment: @MaartenDev, no output during executing command (I guess no)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a error in angular version 12.2.12 and 12.2.11 use 12.2.10 it will fix it or you might have to wait for them to release a new version or fix 12.2.12

Note : if you are using ^12.0.1 in your package.json file, replace it with 12.2.10

Comment: It seems to be not fixed in 12.2.13.

Answer (score 1):

1. First move to a latest stable release
2. remove package-lock.json
3. npm install

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by the [improved UMD module detection](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/43879) added in 12.2.11, pinning the version to 12.2.10 avoids the issue but doesn't address the root cause which is that a dependency probably needs updating.

For us, the package was `@auth0/angular-jwt`, but it might be different for you. To find it we had to use Linux tool `strace` to find out which file was opened just before the build failed:

```
strace -f npm run build 2>&1 | egrep 'open|Error'
```

(eventually) produced the output

```
[pid 29550] open(".../node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/package.json", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 19
[pid 29550] open(".../node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/bundles/core.umd.js", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 19
[pid 29550] open(".../node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/bundles/core.umd.js", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 19
[pid 29550] open(".../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/__ngcc_lock_file__", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 19
[pid 29550] write(2, "TypeError: Cannot read property "..., 1535TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
[pid 29582] open(".../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/__ngcc_lock_file__", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
[pid 29582] <... open resumed> )        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 29393] write(2, "(node:29393) UnhandledPromiseRej"..., 914(node:29393) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: NGCC failed.
```

the offending module is opened in the run up to the error, and updating it resolved the problem. There's probably a more succinct shell command to get the error, but this was enough for us.