# How can I determine the Dependency that is breaking NGCC when running `ng build`?

Tags: angular, angular12

I've recently upgraded an Angular 6 app to angular 12, which initially ran okay, but now after a merge with an updated branch in prep for merge, I'm now getting this message when running `ng build` this also is the exact same output with the `--verbose` flag and the contents of the referenced file (in red)

[image: ng build output]

This was just building no issue, and moving to this branch has been an issue in the past, so my build pattern in testing this issue is as follows:

1. `rimraf node_modules/`
2. `rimraf dist/`
3. `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` *this was recommended by `@agm/core` research*
4. `ng build`

So far I've only gotten the same results, and I'm concerned there is a package that's blocking the build process due to not implementing an "Angular Module" according to some issues on Github trying to solve the same issue.

this is my package.json for the angular project, Which one is my little gremlin?

```
{
  "name": "miner-hosting-platform",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start-dev": "ng serve --host=0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "12.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.4.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^7",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.175",
    "@types/mocha": "^7.0.2",
    "angular-highcharts": "^7.2.0",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.1",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.1.5",
    "angular2-google-map-auto-complete": "^2.0.9",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "highcharts": "^9.1.2",
    "highcharts-angular": "*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "ng-block-ui": "^1.0.6",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^0.8.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "*",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "*",
    "@angular/cli": "*",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.16",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.44",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.18",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.66",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Update:
I've followed the advice of this question as well, but it appears to not work either.

[SO Question about NGCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69736513/cannot-read-property-text-of-undefined-at-nodeobject-gettext-at-getrequiredmod)

Comment: Check the log file at the bottom of the output.

Answer (score 1):

So it appears there are a number of factors associated with this setup, the first of which is a browserlist for the error message, but that doesn't fully solve the problem.

Second, There is a current known issue with the angular dev dependencies and the only mention I can find of it is in this other stack overflow question [here. (dev dependency error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69736513/cannot-read-property-text-of-undefined-at-nodeobject-gettext-at-getrequiredmod)

From the question above, it appears that google is planning to have the fix in for version `12.2.13` so until then use `12.2.10` for the dev dependencies to ensure the project builds properly.

Third there were some peer dependencies that were causing problems with the build as well, so there was some massaging to be done in the package.json file.

I had to follow this process until I got a successful build for part 3:

1. Update dependency version
2. delete package-lock.json (because we're making changes outside of npm)
3. `npm i && ng build`